# POST array is empty after the data sent through ajax

Tags: ajax, search, post, livesearch

Again i am stuck with ajax in my code. I am making live search ajax system for my project but when i send the data to search.php & var_dump POST array, I am getting empty post array.

**AJAX**

```
function searching(string){
 $.ajax({
  url  : "request/search.php",
  type : "POST",
  data : "search="+string,
  type : "text",
  beforeSend : function(http){

  },
  success : function(response,status,http){
    alert(response);
  },
   error : function(http,status,error){
        $('.response').html("<span class='error'>Something went wrong</span>");
        $(".response").slideDown();
    }
   })
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="searchBox">
     <p>
       <input type="text" name="search" id="search"  onkeyup="searching(this.value)" placeholder="Search here">
       <button class="find" data-icon="&#xe986;"></button>
     </p>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your `type : "POST",` with `type : "text",`. So you have to remove `type : "text",` and since jQuery 1.9 you should use `method` instead of `type`.

Beside that you should not write  `data : "search="+string,` but use:

```
data : {
   search : string
}
```

instead, because then you can be sure that `string` will be always encoded the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function searching(string){

$.ajax({
     url  : "request/search.php",
     type : "POST",
     data : {'search': string},
     type : "text",
     beforeSend : function(http){

    },
success : function(response,status,http){
     alert(response);
    },
error : function(http,status,error){
    $('.response').html("<span class='error'>Something went wrong</span>");
    $(".response").slideDown();
   }
  })
}
```